# Jasmine not reporting that Angular controller function has been called

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a method defined on a controller and I'm trying to test if it has been called. I am able to test that the method is defined, but when I try and test if it has been called, it complains that it expected the spy to have been called.

Here is my controller:

```
myControllers.controller 'MyCtrl', ($scope) ->
  this.init = () -> doStuff()
  this.init()
```

Here is my test suite:

```
describe "testing myCtrl", () ->
  beforeEach "myControllers"
  $controller = {}
  $scope = {}

  beforeEach inject (_$controller_,$rootScope) ->
    $controller = _$controller_
    $scope = $rootScope.$new()

  describe "MyCtrl", () ->
    beforeEach () -> 
      MyCtrl=$controller('MyCtrl',{$scope:$scope})

    it "should be defined", () -> # passes
      expect(MyCtrl).toBeDefined() 

    it "should define #init", () -> # passes
      expect(angular.isFunction(MyCtrl.init)).toBe true 

    it "should call #init", () -> # fails
      spyOn MyCtrl, 'init'
      expect(MyCtrl.init).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

The last assertion results in **Error: Expected spy init to have been called.**

Answer (score 0):

It's because it gets called right away, so by the time your test hits, it's already ran. Your beforeEach where you create MyCtrl is where it'll get called automatically. You'll have to structure things differently to test.

Comment: How should I structure it? Should I instantiate the controller in the assertion or create the spy in beforeEach?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to the problem is to not have an init() function in my controller. There is no reason for it. Top-level code in the controller is run upon instantiation, wrapping it in an init function is redundant.